# Command doesn't show up on ICommandBar

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#

I'm trying to put a custom command into the Help menu on startup if it isn't already there. This is my code to do so:

```
private void OnCreate()
{
    // other stuff in OnCreate()...
    // registering my method for the right event
    m_appStatusEvents = m_application as IApplicationStatusEvents_Event;
    m_appStatusEvents.Initialized += new IApplicationStatusEvents_InitializedEventHandler(AddCmd);
}

private void AddCmd()
{
    UID myCmdId = new UIDClass();
    myCmdId.Value = myCmdIdValue;  // myCmdIdValue is my command's UID

    ICommandBars commandBars = m_application.Document.CommandBars;

    UID helpMenuId = new UIDClass();
    helpMenuId.Value = helpMenuIdValue; // helpMenuIdValue is esriArcMapUI.MxHelpMenu
    ICommandBar helpMenu = null;
    helpMenu = (ICommandBar)commandBars.Find(helpMenuId, false, false);
    // here, helpMenu.Count is 3
    if (helpMenu != null)
    {
        ICommandItem myCmd = helpMenu.Find(myCmdId, false);
        if (myCmd == null)
        {
            Object index = Type.Missing;
            helpMenu.Add(myCmdId, ref index);
            // here helpMenu.Count is 4, so my command was added
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's pretty straight forward: I'm looking for the Help menu and add my command if it isn't already there. In the debugger, I can see that an item is added to the Help menu, as its `Count` goes from 3 to 4.

Problem is: The command doesn't show up. I can add it manually, so I know it's loaded and correct, it just doesn't show up when I try to add it automatically.

Edit: I just tried to refresh the Help menu with `(helpMenu as ICommandItem).Refresh()` but that didn't help either.

Edit2: I just added this to debug:

```
for (int i = 0; i < helpMenu.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(helpMenu[i].Caption);
}
```

And it shows

- &ArcGIS Desktop-Help
- &ArcGIS Resource Center
- &About ArcMap...
- myCommand Caption

So it's definitely there, it just won't show!

Comment: What exactly is your helpMenuIdValue value? Are you using the GUID {119591D1-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51} to get a handle on the Help Menu?

Comment: I tried both `{119591D1-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51}` and `esriArcMapUI.MxHelpMenu` - both times the command gets added but both times it wont show up in the menu.

Comment: Try casting helpMenu to ICommandItem and call Refresh() after adding command. Also myCmd.Refresh() just to be sure.

Comment: As written in my first edit: casting to `ICommandItem` and calling `Refresh` has no effect on the menu. I now tried it with `myCommand`, too. No effect.